# WPF MouseDown event on FrameworkElement object

Tags: wpf, events, mouseevent, frameworkelement

I have a WPF Application that receive `FrameworkElement` objects from 3rd party API.

I would like to register events on those objects.
Is this possible? This not working:

```
    public void DisplayControl(FrameworkElement control)
    {
        control.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(Control_MouseEnter);
        control.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Control_MouseDownFromElement);
        VideoGrid.Children.Add(control);
    }

    void Control_MouseDownFromElement(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblOutput.Content = string.Format("Sender is: " + sender.ToString());
    }
    void Control_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as FrameworkElement).Focus(); 
    }
```

Comment: Why is this not working? If the control is already the child of another control, you cannot add it to `VideoGrid`.

Comment: In this certain case the control is WindowsFormsHost that hold a WinForm control, and then DisplayControl receive it already wrapped. the control is displayed properly but does not fire events.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is the control provider is intentionally blocking that event... you can try adding a control(say grid) on the top of the original control with 0.01 opacity means virtually the control we have added is not visible to the user and we can write all the events on the invisible control...

**Update**

Something like this... create a grid with opacity 0.01 add events to that grid and add the grid to the video grid after adding your control... so in the video grid there will be control and on the top of the control there will be grid which is invisible because of its opacity and your events will work on the grid... make sure to give same height and width to the grid that match with your control height and width....

```
Grid grd = new Grid(); 
grd.Opacity = 0.01; 
grd.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Grid_MouseDown_1);
VideoGrid.Children.Add(control);
VideoGrid.Children.Add(grd)
```

Comment: you mean: Grid grd = new Grid(); grd.Opacity = 0.01;  grd.Children.Add(camera); grd.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Grid_MouseDown_1); VideoGrid.Children.Add(grd);
It does not work